# Visual Studio 2015, OneDrive - aspx.vb page needs to access files from OneDrive

Tags: .net, vb.net, onedrive

I have an in-house application written in ASP.net and VB and need to access OneDrive for pictures and display them in my application based on certain conditions.

Need assistance on how to connect and read from OneDrive please.

Comment: Which part of the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/docs) do you have a problem with? Your question might be considered to be too broad for Stack Overflow at the moment.

Comment: "Need assistance" is a little bit vague. What have you tried so far? Are you getting any error messages/unexpected behavior?

Comment: As I read more, I found that I need to learn more about Microsoft Graph.  Thanks.